# Restsharp oAuth 2 legged auth error : Invalid signature for signature method HMAC-SHA1

Tags: c#, security, oauth, restsharp

We are consuming an API which supports OAuth 2 legged authentication.  I'm getting this error below when trying to run my rest sharp client OAuth1Authenticator implemenation:

> **Message**: HTTP Status 401 - Invalid signature for signature method HMAC-SHA1
>
> **Description**:  This request requires HTTP authentication (Invalid
>   signature for signature method HMAC-SHA1).

Here's the code snippet:

```
var restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            restClient.Authenticator =
                OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerKey"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerSecret"], string.Empty, string.Empty);

            var request = new RestRequest(relativePath);
            request.AddParameter(new Parameter { Name = "username", Value = username, Type = ParameterType.QueryString });
            request.AddParameter(new Parameter { Name = "firstname", Value = firstname, Type = ParameterType.QueryString });
            request.AddParameter(new Parameter { Name = "surname", Value = surname, Type = ParameterType.QueryString });
            request.AddParameter(new Parameter { Name = "email", Value = email, Type = ParameterType.QueryString });
            request.AddParameter(new Parameter { Name = "password", Value = password, Type = ParameterType.QueryString });


            request.Resource = string.Format(relativePath);
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            var response = restClient.Execute<object>(request);
```

It appears to me that we need to pass the signature with request. But just haven't figured out how to pass this using RestSharp.

Could someone point me to right direction?

**UPDATE**

Interestingly when I used custom OAuthBase class below for signing the request. It works well.
http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs

I really would like to use RestSharp without writing any custom code. Not sure what exactly am I doing wrong.

Comment: This looks intersting https://www.drupal.org/node/1991416 Its drupal but gist is that signatures don't match because the server and the client are using different hashing mechanisms

Comment: Had a look at your link but I could not relate this resharp problem. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the first comment ?  The gist was to check that the signature of the server and the client is using the same

Comment: Problem here is i'm not able to send the signature. I only have consumer key and secret key. Not sure how to pass signature using RestSharp

Comment: Does this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954935/etsy-oauth-authentication-c-sharp-restsharp

Comment: It's a 2 legged oauth implementation. See my update please.

Answer (score -2):

You are passing in empty strings for your access token and access token secret.

```
restClient.Authenticator =
            OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerKey"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerSecret"], string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

Looking at a [RestSharp test example](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/oAuth1Tests.cs) it is making sure that the values are provided.  Try using that site as a template and see if populating those values helps.

Comment: Our provider doesn't provide those extra parameters. Per my last update the OAuthBase.cs works with passing empty values for the other two methods.